# SQL Server conditional full text index creation

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Following query fails when a server instance doesn't support full text search, despite the IF clause. Does anyone know, why it happens and how to achieve such conditional index creation?

```
IF ((select SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')) = 1)
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
      ON dbo.FulltextSearchIntermediates(
        [ContentUnderstand] LANGUAGE 1049
        ) 
      KEY INDEX [PK_dbo.FulltextSearchIntermediates] ON QuestionsFTS
```

the error message is:

> "Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably means it is failing at compile time, so you need to keep sql from trying to compile if full text is not installed.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
      ON dbo.salesforcecontact(
        [LastName] LANGUAGE 1049
        ) 
      KEY INDEX [PK_dbo.FulltextSearchIntermediates] ON LastName'

IF ((select SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')) = 1)
    exec sp_executesql '@sql'
```

Comment: cool, that helps, thanks! but it should be "declare @sql Nvarchar(max)"